# Django Template - Iterating on lists

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 2 models defined as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, null=False)

class List(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='joining')
    list = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False, unique=False)
```

Querying the Article

```
class InboxView(SomeMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = '...'
    context_object_name = 'article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('joining')
```

On my template, this works:

```
{% for article in article_list %} {{ article.title }} {% endfor %}
```

But this does not

```
{% for article in article_list %} {{ article.list }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are the models related?

Comment: Yes, field2 in Child references Parent

Comment: What kind of relationship is it? (You might just show your models.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need this instead:

```
{% for article in article_list %}
  {{ article.title }}
  {% for t in article.joining.all %}
    {{ t.list }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since you are iterating through [the "other" side of the relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) (i.e. articles), you will access each article's related `List` via the article's list_set (to which [you have given the related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) 'joining').

Incidentally, you might want to find a different name for your `List` model. It makes this discussion somewhat confusing.

Comment: It still prints article.title but not t.list

Comment: BTW I have specified how I write the query in more details

Comment: @user1477118 Ah, I see! You have given a `related_name` to your `foreign_key`. Instead of `list_set` you will use `joining` instead. Try the above code in my updated answer.

Comment: @user1477118 Great! I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access child.field this way. If your parent child are properly referenced, you have to do like:

```
{% for parent in parent_list %}
    my parent value: {{parent.field1}}
    {%for child in parent.child_set.all %}
        My child value {{child.field2}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question, so now what would I write instead of parent.child in the second loop? Thank you!

Comment: Since your parent (Article) consist many child (List), you should do a for loop. You have one-to-many relation. If don't want to do that change youe module for one-to-one relation.